# Why does starting StreamingContext fail with “IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute”?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to execute a Spark Streaming example with Twitter as the source as follows:

```
public static void main (String.. args) {

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark_Streaming_Twitter").setMaster("local");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);       
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(2));      
        JavaSQLContext sqlCtx = new JavaSQLContext(sc);     


        String[] filters = new String[] {"soccer"};

        JavaReceiverInputDStream<Status> receiverStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(jssc,filters);



         jssc.start();
         jssc.awaitTermination();

}
```

But I'm getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No output streams registered, so nothing to execute
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.validate(DStreamGraph.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.validate(StreamingContext.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:437)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.start(JavaStreamingContext.scala:501)
    at org.learning.spark.TwitterStreamSpark.main(TwitterStreamSpark.java:53)
```

Any suggestion how to fix this issue?

Comment: you're not doing anything with the stream just perform an operation on it and ur good to go

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> When an output operator is called, it triggers the computation of a
>   stream.

Without output operator on DStream no computation is invoked. basically you will need to invoke any of below method on stream

```
print()
foreachRDD(func)
saveAsObjectFiles(prefix, [suffix])
saveAsTextFiles(prefix, [suffix])
saveAsHadoopFiles(prefix, [suffix])
```

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations

you can also first apply any transformations and then output functions too if required.

Answer (score 3):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No output streams registered, so nothing to execute

**TL;DR** Use one of the available [output operators](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams) like `print`, `saveAsTextFiles` or `foreachRDD` (or less often used `saveAsObjectFiles` or `saveAsHadoopFiles`).

In other words, you have to use an output operator between the following lines in your code:

```
JavaReceiverInputDStream<Status> receiverStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(jssc,filters);
// --> The output operator here <--
jssc.start();
```

Quoting the Spark official documentation's [Output Operations on DStreams](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams) (highlighting mine):

> **Output operations** allow DStream's data to be pushed out to external systems like a database or a file systems. Since the output operations actually allow the transformed data to be consumed by external systems, they **trigger the actual execution of all the DStream transformations (similar to actions for RDDs)**.

The point is that without an output operator you have *"no output streams registered, so nothing to execute"*.

As one commenter has noticed, you have to use an output transformation, e.g. `print` or `foreachRDD`, before starting the `StreamingContext`.

---

Internally, whenever you use one of the available output operators, e.g. `print` or `foreach`, `DStreamGraph` is requested to [add an output stream](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/DStreamGraph.scala#L97-L102).

You can find the registration when a [new ForEachDStream is created and registered](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStream.scala#L651-L656) afterwards (which is exactly to [add it as an output stream](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStream.scala#L935-L938)).

Answer (score 1):

It also -*wrongly*- fails accusing this problem, but **the real cause** is the **non multiple numbers** between the slide window durations from streaming input and the RDD time windows. 
**It only logs a warning**: you fix it, and the context stops failing :D