# Spark: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

the following question is similar: [Spark Streaming with Twitter - No output streams registered, so nothing to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519660/spark-streaming-with-twitter-no-output-streams-registered-so-nothing-to-execu) however I think that in line `51` using `wordCounts.print()` I actually do output some results.

Basic Code:

```
ssc.start()
      ssc.awaitTermination()
      val lines = messages.map(_._2)
      val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
      val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1L)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
      wordCounts.print()
```

Or do I misunderstand something here?
To follow along:
https://github.com/dataplayground/playground/blob/master/app/actors/DirectStreamingActor.scala

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Should be last in your code.

Answer (score 2):

> Since the output operations actually allow the transformed data to be consumed by external systems, they trigger the actual execution of all the DStream transformations (similar to actions for RDDs).

From http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams

So it's actually because you didn't do any of the output operations when you `start()`. When you move `start()` and `awaitTermination()` to the last position in your code, you did the output operation hence it works.