# Error at jscc.start()

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Here is my Spark Code and pom.xml. The issue with this program is JavaStreamingContext is streaming only first batch of records, it's not streaming any further and i am getting error at jscc.start().
Can anyone give me some clue on why this is happening. Is there anything wrong with my spark dependencies?

> 17/04/11 10:32:20 ERROR StreamingContext: Error starting the context, marking it as stopped
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute
>       at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.validate(DStreamGraph.scala:163)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.validate(StreamingContext.scala:513)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:573)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:572)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.start(JavaStreamingContext.scala:554)
>       at com.comcast.emm.vodip.WholeTextLocal.WholeTextLocal.main(WholeTextLocal.java:72)
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute
>       at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.validate(DStreamGraph.scala:163)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.validate(StreamingContext.scala:513)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:573)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:572)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.start(JavaStreamingContext.scala:554)
>       at com.comcast.emm.vodip.WholeTextLocal.WholeTextLocal.main(WholeTextLocal.java:72)

Code: pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.abcd.emm.mpp</groupId>
    <artifactId>WholeTextLocal</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>WholeTextLocal</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>



    <build>
        <plugins>


            <!-- Maven Shade Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>

                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>

                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>

                            <transformers>
                                <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.abcd.emm.mpp.WholeTextLocal.WholeTextLocal</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>


            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId> 
            <version>2.4.4</version> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0_101</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- required at run time by hive -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sparkjava/spark-core -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sparkjava/spark-core -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.11 -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId> 
            <version>2.0.2</version> <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10 -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11 -->

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId> 
            <version>2.0.2</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive_2.10 -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive_2.10 -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive_2.11 -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-metastore</artifactId>
            <version>0.14.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.avro/avro-tools -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>log4j</groupId> <artifactId>log4j</artifactId> 
            <version>1.2.17</version> </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId> <artifactId>scalatest_2.10</artifactId> 
            <version>2.2.4</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Java code:

```
package com.comcast.emm.vodip.WholeTextLocal;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;

import scala.Tuple2;

public class WholeTextLocal
    {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
            {

                SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("My app").setMaster("local")
                        .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");

                JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(15));

                JavaPairRDD<String, String> WholeTextLocalFiles = jssc.sparkContext()
                        .wholeTextFiles("C:/Users/aaa/files/abcd7/simple/*.txt");

                // Pick the content.
                JavaRDD<String> myRDD = WholeTextLocalFiles.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>()
                    {
                        private static final long serialVersionUID = -551872585218963131L;

                        public String call(Tuple2<String, String> v1) throws Exception
                            {
                                System.out.println("v1._2=" + v1._2);
                                return v1._2;
                            }

                    });

                // Split the content in each file with /n character.
                JavaRDD<String> myRDD2 = myRDD.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>()
                    {

                        public Iterator<String> call(String t) throws Exception
                            {

                                return Arrays.asList(t.split("\\r?\\n")).iterator();

                            }
                    });

                // Loop through and print.
                myRDD2.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<String>>()
                    {

                        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4895942417886562330L;

                        public void call(Iterator<String> t) throws Exception
                            {
                                while (t.hasNext())
                                    {
                                        System.out.println(t.next());
                                    }

                            }
                    });

                jssc.start();
                jssc.awaitTermination();

            }

    }
```

UPDATED CODE: this is streaming. but, sysout is not printing anything eventhough file is being recognized by spark.

```
public class WholeTextLocal
    {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
            {

                SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("My app").setMaster("local")
                        .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");

                JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(10));


                JavaPairInputDStream<Text, Text> dStream = jssc.fileStream("C:/Users/aaa/files/abcd7/simple/", Text.class, Text.class, WholeTextFileInputFormat.class);



                // Pick the content.
                JavaDStream<String> myRDD = dStream.map(new Function<Tuple2<Text, Text>, String>()
                    {
                        private static final long serialVersionUID = -551872585218963131L;

                        @Override
                        public String call(Tuple2<Text, Text> v1) throws Exception
                            {
                                System.out.println("v1._2=" + v1._1);
                                return v1._2.toString();
                            }

                    });


                // Split the content in each file with /n character.
                JavaDStream<String> myRDD2 = myRDD.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>()
                    {                       
                        @Override
                        public Iterator<String> call(String t) throws Exception
                            {

                                return Arrays.asList(t.split("\\r?\\n")).iterator();

                            }
                    });

                // Loop through and print.

                myRDD2.foreachRDD(itr -> new VoidFunction<Iterator<String>>()
                    {
                        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4895942417886562330L;

                        @Override
                        public void call(Iterator<String> t) throws Exception
                            {
                                while (t.hasNext())
                                    {
                                        System.out.println(t.next());
                                    }

                            }
                    }); 


                myRDD2.count();

                jssc.start();
                jssc.awaitTermination();

            }

    }
```

Comment: The above issues are different. What ever the action i added, is not making the streaming to continue.

Comment: @AKC That's because you use normal Spark context to read the data - you should use streaming context. See my answer

Comment: @RC. This question IS NOT a duplicate. Lack of action is only the first problem, there is a second error

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612401/streaming-streamingcontext-error-starting-the-context-marking-it-as-stopped-s, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519660/spark-streaming-with-twitter-no-output-streams-registered-so-nothing-to-execu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that error message tells you everything:

> **No output operations registered, so nothing to execute at**

You must add some action at the end, i.e. foreachRDD instead of foreachPartition:

```
myRDD2.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4895942417886562330L;

    public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
        rdd.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<String>>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;
            public void call(Iterator<String> rdd) throws Exception {
              while (t.hasNext()) {
              System.out.println(t.next());
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Note: you can use foreachPartition inside foreachRDD

Second:

you are reading files using `JavaRDD.wholeTextFiles`. It's not a streaming function. You should read using `JavaStreamingContext.textFileStream` and operate on `DStreams`

You can use also `fileStream` with input format like WholeTextFileInputFormat:

```
JavaPairInputDStream<Text, Text> dStream = jssc.fileStream("dir", Text.class, Text.class, WholeTextFileInputFormat.class);
```

Comment: Thank you..Is there a way that i could streaming functionality for wholeTextFiles.

Comment: `textFileStream` is doing it ;)

Comment: I need the filenames too so trying to use WholeTextFiles.

Comment: Is it possible to use WholeTextFiles with streaming functionality??..Temporarily i am using infinite loop around WholeTextFiles.

Comment: @AKC Please see suggested modification

Comment: I tried to use fileStream. JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> dStream = ; This is expecting Text types instead of string. JavaPairInputDStream<Text, Text> dStream. Type mismatch: cannot convert from JavaPairInputDStream<Text,Text> to JavaPairInputDStream<String,String>

Comment: @AKC Yes, but Text is just a wrapper for a String - you can now use map to map (Text, Text) tuple to (String, String) tuple, like you want to have in your system :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141467/discussion-between-akc-and-t-gaweda).