# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-zeppelin, spark-cassandra-connector

When I execute the code below give the error
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute"
Anybody can help me please?

```
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))

    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)


   var imput: SimpleDateFormat   = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",  Locale.ENGLISH)
   var dia: SimpleDateFormat   = new SimpleDateFormat("dd")
   var mes: java.text.SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
   var ano: java.text.SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");

var diacv: String = ""
var mescv: String = ""
var anocv: String = ""

case class Data(diacv: String, mescv: String, anocv: String)

val columns = Seq("timecol")


val data = ssc.cassandraTable("smartgrids","analyzer_temp")
              .select(columns.map(ColumnName(_)).take(1):_*)


val dstream = new ConstantInputDStream(ssc, data)


class foo() {


import sqlContext.implicits._

        val result = dstream.map(row => (
                     diacv = dia.format(imput.parse(row.toString())), 
                     mescv = mes.format(imput.parse(row.toString())), 
                     anocv = ano.format(imput.parse(row.toString()))
                   )           
       ).toDF()

             result.registerTempTable("result") 

            // return result
}

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Streaming with Twitter - No output streams registered, so nothing to execute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519660/spark-streaming-with-twitter-no-output-streams-registered-so-nothing-to-execu)

Comment: What exactly this code should do?

Comment: This code is to extract part of date. My data is in cassandra table, the code read the column, "timecol", that have date in format "2015-08-21 04:01:00+0000". e.g the line diacv = dia.format(imput.parse(row.toString())), extract the day, it work when i do diacv = dia.format(imput.parse("2015-08-21 04:01:00+0000")). But when i pass cassandra row it give error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem,the Stream doesn't have output operation. Add below func will be ok

`print() foreachRDD(func) saveAsObjectFiles(prefix, [suffix]) saveAsTextFiles(prefix, [suffix]) saveAsHadoopFiles(prefix, [suffix])`